# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel autoplay on load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Using the twitter bootstrap framework, how is it possible to invoke the carousel to 'auto slide.' Meaning when the page loads, the carousel automatically scrolls.

I have tried a javascript onLoad click function for the `<a>` of the next link, but this didn't work.

Comment: It should start playing automatically without you having to do anything. Ca you manually click previous/next links and it works?

Comment: CoffeeScript autoplay: $ -> $('#myCarousel').carousel()

Comment: Simple add word 'auto' to div class 
<div id="yourID" class="carousel slide **auto**">

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the boostrap js carousel automatically cycle as soon as the page loads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750816/how-can-i-make-the-boostrap-js-carousel-automatically-cycle-as-soon-as-the-page)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

you should do as the [Twitter Bootstrap Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) says about Carousel, so set the first Carousel slide item with **class="active"** and initialize the js for the carousel in this way:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
});
```

then if it's not enough (but this never happened to me) use the bruteforce triggering the click hover the carousel control buttons like this:

```
$(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
$('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
});
```

but this is just a not-needed trick, really, just follow the documentantion!

Comment: @merv sincerily i never got troubles with carousel, it's just to follow what the bootstrap doc says

Comment: Obviously the time on my first comment indicates that it referred to the original edit of your answer, which did have bad info. While the later revision is more correct I still don't understand why the mention of artificially triggering events is included.

Comment: I've found that if you set one of the img items with class="active" you don't need to use that trick with triggering the next slide.

Comment: @MegaTux yeah true, just use that indeed, 'my' trick is not needed, carousel starts by default, then class=active sets which is the first image you want to show ;)

Comment: Thank you! Your *bruteforce* triggering Method is super awesome!

Comment: @Eirenaios well it should be not-needed :P anyway glad that it helps ;)

Comment: @Eirenaios - it is anything but super awesome. if you need it, it just conceals another problem in your code. if so, you should fix the original problem instead of covering up your mess with a trick. trust me, it will come back to bite you. it ALWAYS does.

Comment: oh u r a genius you saved me.. Awesome solution. Thanks a lot +1

Answer (score 24):

Simple.  You're missing the "data-ride" attribute in the div.

`<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`

Comment: liked the css approach.

Answer (score 8):

As [per the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel), you need to initialize the Carousel plugin via JavaScript. The carousel example on the official Bootstrap documentation page is initialized in the **application.js** file on lines 67-68:

```
// carousel demo
$('#myCarousel').carousel()
```

which gives it the default settings.

If you want to specify the cycle interval, you can set the `interval` property in milliseconds:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

Comment: Being a wholly relevant answer with accurate information supported by an appropriate amount of background info, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Put it in the document-ready-block make it auto-start for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` works for me, what I have been missing was the data-ride attribute.

I  hope this will help a lot of people. 
Thank you stackoverflow, you have been very useful to me on most grounds. Am glad this community exists.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `data-interval="5000"` to the `div` with the IP `carouselExampleIndicators`.

Like this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **data-interval** attribute on the html markup to auto play:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"  data-interval="5000">
```

**data-interval**: The amount of time in milliseconds to delay between automatically cycling an item. If false, carousel will not automatically cycle.

Comment: I am facing an issue with my carousel even tho I have used the above setting..its not coming as desired and initially not initaiting the carousel

Answer (score 1):

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

YOU NEED ADD

```
data-ride="carousel"

<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 4 and onwards:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000,
      ride: 'carousel' // this is the important part
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply add the class "slide" to the carousel div tag, like this:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="this-carousel-id">
```

Comment: -1 That only enables css transition functionality, but still does not initialize the Carousel plugin, which is what is required.