# Moving slide in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the carousel of bootstrap, for this I have in my js folder all this file.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

and my carousel is this.

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item"><img src="img/cabecera/slide1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/cabecera/slide3.jpg"></div>
            ...
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
```

The problem is that the fist time the carousel don´t pass the slide, I have to press the left or right arrow to pass the slide , when I press the fist time the slide move alone.

What is wrong?  I miss something.

Comment: You may remove js/bootstrap.js because js/bootstrap.min.js is the same this make your site faster ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you it's the same question as here [How can I make the Bootstrap js carousel automatically cycle as soon as the page loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750816/how-can-i-make-the-boostrap-js-carousel-automatically-cycle-as-soon-as-the-page)

According this the solution for your Problem is a bit js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    });

    $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
});
```