# Bootstrap Carousel not slidong on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap carousel still not works after trying all methods mentioned in below post. Are there any other solutions to resolve this problem? Please help Thanks!

Carousel is not sliding until first click on arrows. I would like to start as soon as page loads.

I have tried all options mentioned in the below post.

[How can I make the Bootstrap js carousel automatically cycle as soon as the page loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750816/how-can-i-make-the-boostrap-js-carousel-automatically-cycle-as-soon-as-the-page)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000
});

 $('.myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Here is the solution.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#myCarousel').carousel(
   {interval: 1000  }
  );
  $('#myCarousel').carousel().next();

});
```