# Joomla 3.4 Bootstrap carousel doesn't slide automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, carousel

Here is my webpage http://www.qkiz.pl/wege2/
I was doing all tricks from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750816/how-can-i-make-the-boostrap-js-carousel-automatically-cycle-as-soon-as-the-page) but nothing works. Google Chrome display error in devtools console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

in http://www.qkiz.pl/wege2/templates/wege2/js/karuzela-timing.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla imports Mootools, thus uses noConflict mode with jQuery.

Try calling the carousel like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :) Adding word 'jQuery' at beginning of script makes it works :)