# Carousel not autoplaying nor clickable (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Y'all I'm losing my mind. I've spent days on this site and others trying different code snippets.

When I preview in jsfiddle, everything is fine. But on my site, it doesn't autoplay and I can't click the nav buttons either. Help!

Live site here: [www.zjscreations.com](http://htp://zjscreations.com/)

```
<section>
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
       interval: 2000
    });
});
</script>
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/Hanna Edens Headshot - Alki Beach.jpg" alt="Hanna Edens Heashot - Alki Beach" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/Stella Salsbury - Dog Portrait.jpg" alt="Stella Salsbury - Dog Portrait" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="/images/Hanna Edens Headshot - Seattle Skyline.jpg" alt="Hanna Edens Heashot - Seattle Skyline" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->

 <a class="carousel-control left" href="#my_carousel" data-slide = "prev">
    <span class="icon-prev left"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#my_carousel" data-slide = "next">
    <span class="icon-next right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: tried jsifddle?

Comment: Have you loaded correctly the .js files from bootstrap?

Comment: Your jquery isn't loading:
http://zjscreations.com/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Comment: check the developer console $ is undefined , no jquery

Comment: Fixed that, thanks guys. Still wasn't working, but I think I got it!

Answer (score 1):

After testing on your site it showed that the **jQuery** library isn't loading correctly, it seems the path you provide isn't accurate. Try fixing the ***url*** of the jQuery **js** file.

[image: Screenshot from your site showing the exact error:]

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that and was still having issues. Finally sorted it out. Have no idea why it works, but I had to add two calls.

Comment: If you'd like to share the working code, I might help you sorting this out, and get rid of the second call :)

Comment: Working code was this:

'<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel(
    {
    interval:2000
    });
});

jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel();
</script>'

Comment: From what I see the second call will be executed first, and when the page is ready it will call the first. If you remove the second call `jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel();` it will stay working; but you need to wait until the page is ready and then autoplay will start.

Comment: Absolutely :) Done

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the jQuery library, but it still wasn't working. I had to change the script code to the following.

I have no idea why it worked, and neither did the OP (thanks [byronyasgur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10969272/7353127)!), so if anyone has insight into why this fixed it, that'd be rad. (That way I'll know for the future instead of just copy/pasting code)

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel(
    {
    interval:2000
    });
});

jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly add this lines at end of your page

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```